# The relation between verbs and their prepositions

Tags: verbs, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

As we know, we use phrasal verbs in which we put prepositions(and adverbs) after verbs that affect the meaning of the action mentioned in the sentence. For instance, taking the example of the verb *run*(used in past tense in the examples), we can have the following sentences:-

1. John *ran into* his teacher at the theater.
2. The inspector *ran after*  the criminal.
3. David *ran away* on seeing the ghost.

In all the above sentences the preposition affects the action being performed. However, I see no way to know what should be the preposition should be used after a particular verb.

**So, is there any way to determine what preposition may be used with a particular verb?**

Note: I am only concerned with the prepositions that come after verbs. So, I have not used phrasal verbs involving adverbs in the sentences.

Comment: The first thing you need to realise is that the structures of 'Joe ran up a large hill' and 'Joe ran up a large bill' are very different, though they are formally identical. The first uses the simplex verb 'run' and the prepositional phrase 'up a large hill' (probably as a directional); the second uses the transitive multi-word verb 'run up' (= amass/incur) and the direct object 'a large bill'.  _And grey areas exist_. // I have a volume on multi-word verbs (though it still uses the traditional name 'phrasal verbs'); it's hundreds of pages long. // I wouldn't use 'Joe ran above a large hill'.

Comment: Ok, I understand that but the main problem lies here,

Comment: In sentence (1),"John ran into his teacher.", how is "into" making sense?

Comment: ''Run into' is an obligatorily transitive obligatorily inseparable multi-word verb meaning either 'encounter by chance' or 'collide with'. Possibly, 'The debt ran into thousands of dollars' and  'We've run into a problem' are just metaphorical extensions. 'Run into' is a cohesive unit here.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. English has  huge number of 'verbal idioms' (that's their correct name) and you'll just have to familiarise yourself with which verbs select which prepositions. Incidentally, I'd strongly advise you to drop the term 'phrasal verb'. It's a misnomer and best avoided since these expressions are not multi-verb phrases --  at word level "ran into", for example, is not a verb, but separate constituents, verb + preposition.

Comment: @BillJ I've been reading the book [Word for Word](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01HA4P9VI/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1), and the author, a professional lexicographer, uses the term "phrasal verb" to describe these idioms. It also appears in a number of dictionaries. It's a particular type of idiom made up of a verb along with an adverb and/or preposition, and acts together as a verb. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs